# Visual Studio Express 2012 how to hide the compilation details when the build is success and show it when the build fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is really annoying, I´m used to see the compilation details **only** when the build fails, otherwise I´m happy just checking the message at the status bar saying *build success*. But it appears on every build...

I´m trying Visual Studio Express 2012 and I have not found the setting required to get this effect

Any ideas?

Comment: This is how every version of Visual Studio works.  You could also just hide the output window, if you do that, the window that contains errors only shows up if there are errors.  Of course a build can fail for reasons not caused by errors when it compiles.

Comment: Even when u hide it, it reappears again on every build

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In VS 2012: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General

- Check 'Always show Error List if build finishes with errors'
- Uncheck 'Show Output window when build starts'

Comment: Yes! Thank you!  It's a little thing but it is so nice not to have to keep searching around when you can't afford the time.  Finding what you are looking for in options rarely seems intuitive to me.

Comment: This still works in VS 2013.  That stupid output window has been annoying me and messing up my layout for years.